# Splitting Transaction across Multiple Views

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out how to split a transaction across multiple views. This is what I have in mind:

1. I have a view which creates a number of records (all packaged into a single transaction);
2. The view presents some information on these changes and also a form which allows the user to either accept or reject;
3. On the basis of the user's choice, the transaction should either be committed or rolled back.

The code that I have looks like this at present:

```
@transaction.non_atomic_requests
def record_results(request):
   if request.method=='POST':
     if "approve" in request.POST:
       transaction.commit()
       transaction.set_autocommit(True)
     if "reject" in request.POST:
       transaction.rollback()
     # Turn AUTOCOMMIT back on again.
     transaction.set_autocommit(True)
     return render(request, 'updated.html')

   approve = ApproveForm()
   # Turn off AUTOCOMMIT.
   transaction.set_autocommit(False)
   # Create records here.
   # [...]
   context = {
       'approve': approve,
   }
   return render(request, 'accept.html', context)
```

Based on my understanding of the documentation, I thought that this would work. However, it does not do as I expected, so I suspect my understanding is flawed.

If I comment out `transaction.set_autocommit(False)` then the data is committed, but immediately rather than after being approved. If `transaction.set_autocommit(False)` is included then no data is committed at all.

Is the problem perhaps due to the transaction being split across two invocations of the view? I'm using `request.session` as well in the same view. Could that have an influence?

Any help or suggestions appreciated. Or, alternatively, if there is an overall better approach to the approval process, I'd be happy to adopt that as an alternative.

I'm working with InnoDB tables on MySQL.

Thank you and best regards, Andrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are local to a single thread in a process (since connections are, and transactions are tied to a single connection), and requests are routed to an arbitrary thread in an arbitrary process. Even with a single thread and process, you can't guarantee that there are no other requests in between -- and having a single thread serving requests absolutely kills your site's performance and scalability by disallowing any concurrency. Transactions also block other threads from using and altering the same data, so transactions should be as short-lived as possible, or you will again block concurrent requests from completing.

You can -- assuming the original changes are based on a form -- render the same form on the confirmation page using hidden inputs, without saving the data to the database. When the user approves the changes, you have the same input as form data, and you can easily save the data during the confirmation request.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding processes, connections and transactions. That certainly clarified the issue. I'm not too worried about the performance impact because this scenario would be rather rare (manually uploading of data). And, unfortunately, the data in question are not submitted via a form: they come from a CSV and are subject to some processing before being added to the database.

Comment: In that case you could save the CSV on disk to a temporary location and save the file path in the session. Then on confirmation you load the file and process it.

Comment: That seems like a decent solution to me. Thanks!

Comment: Just for my understanding, could you clarify: each new request (and hence each new call of a view) happens in a separate connection, so there is no reasonable way to have a transaction bridging across multiple requests? In retrospect this seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Each new request happens in a (more or less) random thread, and each thread has a separate connection. That means that most of the time two successive requests will indeed use different connections. A single thread can reuse a connection for multiple requests as an optimization, but there's no way to guarantee two requests are handled by the same thread.